# Dart: How to create new list Using Existing List?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter .
I am trying to create new list from below list

```
 var itemlist1=[
          {"p_id": "a101", "model": "M-Plaz","price": 2500},
          {"p_id": "a101", "model": "Z-Plaz","price": 3500},
          {"p_id": "a102", "model": "M-Neo", "price": 1560},
          {"p_id": "a102", "model": "N-Neo1","price": 3600}];
```

Output list should be like below

```
var newlist=[{"Subitems":[
    {
        "p_id":"a101",
        "items": [
            {"p_id": "a101", "model": "M-Plaz","price": 2500},
          {"p_id": "a101", "model": "Z-Plaz","price": 3500}     
        ]},{
        "p_id": "a102",
        "items": [
           {"p_id": "a102", "model": "M-Neo", "price": 1560},
          {"p_id": "a102", "model": "N-Neo1","price": 3600}
        ]},
    ]
}];
```

please i need help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code gives you the required output.

```
var itemlist1 = [
      {"p_id": "a101", "model": "M-Plaz", "price": 2500},
      {"p_id": "a101", "model": "Z-Plaz", "price": 3500},
      {"p_id": "a102", "model": "M-Neo", "price": 1560},
      {"p_id": "a102", "model": "N-Neo1", "price": 3600}
    ];

    var newlist = groupBy(itemlist1, (Map obj) => obj['p_id']);

    var requiredOutput = [
      {"Subitems": []}
    ];
    newlist.forEach((k, v) => {
          requiredOutput[0]["Subitems"]!.add({"p_id": k, "items": v})
        });

    print(requiredOutput);
```

Note: Add `import "package:collection/collection.dart";` line in imports.

Comment: @srikantha nayak no need of thanks. if the solution is work for you then reply as it's working otherwise reply as it's not working or something else. then the person who is answering your question may get clarity about his answer.

Comment: got it sir.. im new here. so you good people are  helping me.. by now i will reply revery answers . thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

### You can do this by:

```
newlist.addAll([
  {'Subitems': itemlist1}
]);
```

print(newlist.toString());

Comment: okay, let me update.

Comment: now try, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to work directly on a `Map<String, dynamic>` you get from Json. You could rather define a Model for your Products.

```dart
class ProductModel {
  final String pId;
  final String model;
  final double price;
  
  ProductModel({
    required this.pId,
    required this.model,
    required this.price
  });
  
  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    pId = json['p_id'] as String,
    model = json['model'] as String,
    price = json['price'] as double;
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'p_id': pId,
    'model': model,
    'price': price
  };
}
```

*Note: Have a look at the `json_serializable` & `freezed` packages too.*

Then, grouping your Products by id gets easier:

```dart
void main() {
  final List<ProductModel> list =[
    {"p_id": "a101", "model": "M-Plaz","price": 2500},
    {"p_id": "a101", "model": "Z-Plaz","price": 3500},
    {"p_id": "a102", "model": "M-Neo", "price": 1560},
    {"p_id": "a102", "model": "N-Neo1","price": 3600},
  ].map((item) => ProductModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
  final Map<String, List<ProductModel>> processed = list.fold({}, (pMap, productModel) => {
    ...pMap,
    productModel.pId: [...(pMap[productModel.pId] ?? []), productModel]
  });
  print(jsonEncode(processed));
}
```

#### Console log:

```dart
{"a101":[{"p_id":"a101","model":"M-Plaz","price":2500},{"p_id":"a101","model":"Z-Plaz","price":3500}],"a102":[{"p_id":"a102","model":"M-Neo","price":1560},{"p_id":"a102","model":"N-Neo1","price":3600}]}
```

### Remark

With your Output format, in order to get the models for p_id 'a101', you will have to:

```dart
final a101Models = newlist[0]['Subitems']?.singleWhere((product) => product['p_id'] == 'a101')['items']
```

With my recommended solution, it gets easier:

````dart
List<ProductModel> a101Models = processed['a101'];
```
````

Comment: from this code im not getting correct result.

Comment: Yes, with this code, you have to change your Output format. This might make the rest of your application easier. Check my last update on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code snippet:**

```
 var itemlist1=[
          {"p_id": "a101", "model": "M-Plaz","price": 2500},
          {"p_id": "a101", "model": "Z-Plaz","price": 3500},
          {"p_id": "a102", "model": "M-Neo", "price": 1560},
          {"p_id": "a102", "model": "N-Neo1","price": 3600}];

 // list for subItems
  var subItems = [];
  itemlist1.forEach((item){
     
     // check for subitem for p_id already exists or not
     List items =  subItems.where((i)=>
        i['p_id'] == (item)['p_id']
      ).toList();
    
      if(items.length > 0 ){
        (items[0] as Map<String,dynamic>)['items'].add(item);
      }else {
          Map newMap = Map<String,dynamic>();
          newMap.putIfAbsent('p_id', () => (item)['p_id'].toString());
          List newList = [item];
          newMap.putIfAbsent('items', () => newList);
          subItems.add(newMap);
      } 
    });
    
 
   var output = [
      {"Subitems": subItems}
    ];

  print(output);
```